# Wordpress Install Guide Will not Start

Tags: mysql, wordpress, error-handling, installation

I have installed Wordpress tons of times in the past and have never encountered an issue like this before. It usually is a pretty straight forward thing. In fact, I have 3 wordpress websites installed successfully on my computer from the same zip that I am using today. However, when doing the install this time, for some reason something is different. Wordpress outputs

```
Error establishing a database connection
```

But this makes no sense since all I am trying to do is start the installation process. OF course it is having difficulty establishing a database connection because I have not yet gone through the install process yet. I usually do not need to make a database connection at this point.

So my question is, What could be happening here? How could something which has always worked for me, suddenly stop working? IS there something I am missing? IF anyone can provide me with some information to point me in the right direction, It would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: what did you config? and is your database server working?

Comment: My database and server are working just fine. All my other websites and projects have no problem with running on my install of wamp. And I have not configured anything yet because it will not let me start the installation process, so I have not been given an opportunity to provide wordpress with my database info, etc.

Comment: The you might have entered you user/pass wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your wordpress setup is unable to communicate the database.

The potential reason being incorrect database details in the wp-config.php file. That's the way to do.

Comment: There is no wp-config file. It didnt unzip with one. Usually the wp-config is created after the installation process when ive input the database information into the install guide. But thatz the problem, I cant even get the install guide started.